# Mac OS Login Items with Arguments?

Tags: macos, authentication, applescript, startup

In Mac OS, I've created a few AppleScripts to add and remove start up applications (Login Items, under the Accounts system pane).

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to make new login item with properties { path: \"$1\", hidden:false } at end"
```

Usage would be like this:

```
./addloginitem.sh /Applications/TextEdit.app
```

I'm curious if it's possible to have startup items that use arguments? I have a program that I would like to pass a "startup" argument to if it is running directly after a login.

Comment: Why don´t you create an applescript-application (that opens your program with startup arguments) and than have that as a login item?

Comment: You should add this as an answer, I like it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible however not by using "Login Items". You can use launchd to run commands when you login. It's a little complicated to use compared to login items but they're much more flexible and can do as you request. Just google for launchd instructions, setup the required plist file, and you'd have a powerful method for launching things at login.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to launch GUI applications through launchd?

Comment: launchd runs shell commands, and you can open anything from the shell using the "open" command or you can run applescripts using "osascript".

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can come up with.